# Countdown variable (HH:mm:ss)

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I parse a date YYYY-mm-dd and calculate the difference till midnight. The result will be always under 24h, for example 10:01:10 - HH:mm:ss till it expires. I wonder how I could achieve a countdown functionality with the given example.

```
<template>
    <Label :text="date.expires | readableTime"></Label>
    </template>

    filters: {
        readableTime(value) {
          var now = moment(new Date());
          var end = moment(value);
          var diff = moment.duration(end.diff(now));
          try {
            return moment.utc(diff.as("milliseconds")).format("HH:mm:ss");
          } catch (e) {
            return "00:00:00";
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use use timer and reactive data property. I recommend you to safe diff to components data, start timer on component mount and clear it beforeDestroy

```
data() {
    return {
        diff: this.calculareDiff() 
    }
}

methods: {
    calculareDiff() {
        const now = moment(new Date());
        const end = moment(this.date.expires);
        this.diff = moment.duration(end.diff(now));
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.calculareDiff(), 1000)
},

beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
}
```

Comment: I don't think the Vue.nextTick is relevant.